# What programming language works well with OpenGL ES on iOS and Android?

Tags: android, ios, opengl-es

What programming language works well with OpenGL ES on iOS and Android?

I am specifically looking to get graphics experience with OpenGL ES 2. My experience has been with web development in Javascript and iOS development using C# and Unity3D. (Unity3D is great but far removed from dealing directly with OpenGL ES.)

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is there probably is none.  That's why tools like Unity exist.  Making things work between iOS and Android is a huge difficult task.  If all you need is OpenGL ES experience, why not try it on just one platform?  Both Android and iOS can make calls to Open GL ES, but Android does it in Java while iOS does it in C.

Comment: Is it possible to something like write all game logic in c++, and only use Java for Android and Objective-C for iOS to access the OpenGL ES API?

Comment: I was going to answer with C++, but the wording of your question made me hesitate.  You can use C++ on both Android and iOS, that is certain.  However, I wasn't sure if you would be able to access OpenGL ES commands on Android from C++ (You can from iOS because its OpenGL library is written in C, I assume Android has a backend C library as well, but it is exposed through Java).  However, writing code that is not relevant to the UI or graphics in C++ is definitely a valid option.

Answer (score -1):

If you like C# you should look into MonoTouch. It brings great C# experience to iOS. And it provides you with direct access to OpenGL ES API.